# How do I get the id of a button from onclick method that I set in javascript within a while loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the id of a button (link) that I created in javascript within the onclick method.

I tried this code, but it always displays the id of the last element in the unordered list in the alert, instead of the item that I click.

```
while (index != -1) {

    var select = document.getElementById("recipes");
    var opt = document.createElement("li");
    opt.className = "list-group-item";

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.id = response.substring(0, index);
    link.onclick = function () {
        alert(link.id);
    };
    link.textContent = response.substring(0, index);

    select.appendChild(opt);
    opt.appendChild(link);

    response = response.substring(index + 4);
    index = response.indexOf("~,;~");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All event-listeners in javascript give the opportunity to access to target element using `this`.

Thus :

```
link.onclick = function () {
    alert(this.id);
};
```

And Not :

```
link.onclick = function () {
    alert(link.id);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `alert(this.id);` instead.

`this` always points to the element that called the function, in this case the specific instance of `link` you click on.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is scope. In a situation like this you have to close the values around the event handler so that they are not changed by the loop. Here is an example:

```
while (index != -1) {

    var select = document.getElementById("recipes");
    var opt = document.createElement("li");
    opt.className = "list-group-item";

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.id = response.substring(0, index);

    (function (_link) {
        _link.onclick = function () {
            alert(_link.id);
        };
    })(link);

    link.textContent = response.substring(0, index);

    select.appendChild(opt);
    opt.appendChild(link);

    response = response.substring(index + 4);
    index = response.indexOf("~,;~");
}
```

Using `this` will also work as others have noted. However, it is important to know why using `link.id` does not work here which is a result of scope.